# How to use CustomRenderer to render a different component

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a sample Xamarin.Forms shared project where I have a MainPage.xaml. In order to achieve a material design look on iOS, I'm trying to use custom renderes to give the desired look to the componenets. Recently I found a few dependencies for Xamarin.iOS that can do that.

I would like to know what I need to do in order to use a CustomRenderer to render a compoment from an Xamarin.iOS dependency.

This is my iOS custom renderer for an entry:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace MCTest.iOS
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                // do whatever
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In here I'm able to customize the entry, but what really want to do is rendering a different compoment from a external (nuget) dependency. Is this possible ? If so, how can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: Does that component have its own renderer? If yes, change EntryRenderer with it. It will start to show inherited renderer

Comment: No, I don't believe it has its own renderer. I'm trying to use this dependency: https://github.com/ilap/MaterialComponentsXamarin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create a ContentPage in the PCL, Then make its renderer like:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MaterialPage), typeof(MaterialPageRenderer))]
namespace SpecialPageRenderer.iOS
{
    public class MaterialPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Element != null)
            {
                var materialView = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null).InstantiateViewController("ViewController").View;

                NativeView.AddSubview(materialView);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Here I create a new MaterialViewController on iOS project called `ViewController`. Then I can construct it in this renderer, add its view on the `NativeView`. At last the dependency control will show.

I make a sample for you referring to: https://github.com/landl0526/SpecialMaterialPage

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted based on the sample you provided. Thanks a lot.